# ¿Como puedo hacer un switch a prueba de errores?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, try-catch

Cuando hago un switch habitualmente siempre tengo la preocupación de que alguien vaya a introducir un valor inesperado como un una letra o un caracter especial , mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo forzar el programa a que solamente reciba lo que se espera ? habia escuchado que se puede hacer con un try y catch pero no estoy seguro y no sé exactamente como tiene que ser.

```
int cool;
cin>>cool;
//...
switch(cool){
case 1:
 //..
case 2:
 //...
default:
 //...
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning*.
>
> ― [Rick Cook](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rick_Cook) ―

---

Hoy en día la programación es una carrera entre los ingenieros de software esforzándose por crear mayores y mejores programas a prueba de idiotas y el Universo intentando crear mayores y mejores idiotas. De momento, el Universo va ganando.

---

No existe el algoritmo perfecto a prueba de errores. Pero C++ ofrece herramientas para detectar, controlar y tratar errores. Por desgracia para ti, la instrucción `switch` no es una de esas herramientas.

> ¿Cómo puedo forzar el programa a que solamente reciba lo que se espera?

No puedes, la entrada de datos siempre acepta datos. Pero toda entrada no esperada puede ser ignorada o tratada como error, en el caso de tu código:

```
int cool;
cin>>cool;
//...
switch(cool){
case 1:
 cout << "Todo ha ido bien, Mr/Ms 1\n"; break;
case 2:
 cout << "Todo ha ido bien, Mr/Ms 2\n"; break;
default:
 cerr << "Mi nombre es " << cool << " Montoya, introdujiste un numero incorrecto, preparate a morir\n"; break;
 }
```

> Había escuchado que se puede hacer con un `try` y `catch` [...] no sé exactamente como tiene que ser.

Las excepciones sí son una de las herramientas de C++ para detectar, controlar y tratar errores, en el caso de tu código podría usarse así:

```
bool es_correcto()
{
    int cool;
    cin>>cool;

    switch(cool){
    case 1:
        return true;
    case 2:
        return true;
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("Valor ") + std::to_string(cool) + " no reconocido");
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        if (es_correcto()) { /* hacer cosas */ }
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Algo ha sucedido en la recoleccion de datos! " << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```